# how to set the aspect ratio of an image to 1.91:1

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I need help with how to change an image I have to the aspect ratio of 1.91:1.

Anything I have found online says to use the crop tool and somehow change the AR using the ratio dropdown on the top toolbar[image]

But I have no idea what I do with here and how I can change the AR without affecting the quality of the image

Answer (score 2):

Choose "Ratio" from the dropdown, and type the ratio values in the two boxes, as shown below. Then use the crop tool.

[image]

This will not affect the quality of the image, however it will crop the image and cut away some pixels from the sides depending on the original aspect ratio of the image you are cropping.